# I tried to install mysql now this error appears when I run almost anything in terminal, W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I can't even run sudo apt update without getting this error as a result.
These are the commands I ran in my attempt to install mysql:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
wget -c https://repo.mysql.com//mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
```

I have tried quite a bit to fix this and am now at a loss.

```
user@user_:~$ sudo apt update
    [sudo] password for user: 
    Hit:1 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
    Hit:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
    Hit:3 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
    Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
    Hit:5 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                   
    Hit:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/rael-gc/rvm/ubuntu jammy InRelease      
    Get:7 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease [15,2 kB]
    Err:7 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease
      The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
    Reading package lists... Done
    W: https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
    W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
    E: The repository 'http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try running

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 467B942D3A79BD29
```

It looks like this guy here was having a similar issue.

https://chrisjean.com/fix-apt-get-update-the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-available/